# Massive graphical corruption when playing videos

Tags: 11.04, ati, 64-bit, display

After upgrade my Ubuntu to 11.04 I have a weird problem playing videos. See the [capture from my display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypcQn.png).

I'm getting the same thing with all of the players and video file types.

Ubuntu 11.04 64bit
 ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650

Here's a screenshot (from Oli, that tries to do the video version justice):

[image: Screenshot showing a video with parts of the GNOME UI over it, and being otherwise broken]

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the generic driver for your video card that Ubuntu loaded aren't fully supported by the card,are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Natty?
for the 32 bit and the 64 bit, the Linux driver for your card is here:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

the driver has both 32 and 64 bit in it, however, I can't test it to see if it works,  hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and what I did is just add the `Xorg-edgers` repositories from  http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide  and the problem is solved

I've the same distro 11.04 64-bit and my card is similar I think ATI Mobility Radeon 4430.

I hope this helps.